# Generate XML schema with classes and methods from Java classes - JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there a way in (java - JAXB) to generate a full XML schema that contains all my classes and methods

here is my class

```
public class ConvertUML {

    public static void method1() {
        System.out.println("Print 1");
        }

    public static void method2() {
        System.out.println("Print 2");
        }
}
```

and this is the generated XML from JAXB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="convertUML">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

how can I have method1() and method2() in the schema?

Comment: XML Schema allows to describe data structures,
probably you can use WSDL or OpenAPI formats

Comment: can you guide me on how I can generate WSDL from Java code?